# Swing GUI IOException and FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception, ioexception

I'm trying to load data from a text file into a `JList` using WindowBuilder with the click of a button. As you can see from the code below I'm getting few exceptions that I can't seem to fix. Importing `java.io.FileReader` does not help.

I have a separate class file with the code for my Score vector.

```
    JButton btnLoadData = new JButton("Load Data");
    btnLoadData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String sLine;

            Vector<Score> scoreVec = new Vector<Score>();

            //Here I am getting a FileNotFoundException for (new FileReader("scores.txt")
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scores.txt")); 


            //Here I am getting an IOException for in.readLine()
            while ((sLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                scoreVec.addElement(new Score(sLine));
            }

            //this is also throwing an IOException
            in.close();


            //Placeholders until I get the rest of the program working
            System.out.println(scoreVec.get(1).name);
            System.out.println(scoreVec.get(1).country);
        }
    });
    btnLoadData.setBounds(10, 227, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLoadData);
```

Comment: `new FileReader("scores.txt")` put the high scores in a (sub-directory of a) stable path that is guaranteed readable. That path would be **`user.home`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch and handle the raised exceptions, for example...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    String sLine;

    Vector<Score> scoreVec = new Vector<Score>();

    //Here I am getting a FileNotFoundException for (new FileReader("scores.txt")
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("scores.txt"))) {

        //Here I am getting an IOException for in.readLine()
        while ((sLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            scoreVec.addElement(new Score(sLine));
        }

    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Placeholders until I get the rest of the program working
    System.out.println(scoreVec.get(1).name);
    System.out.println(scoreVec.get(1).country);
}
```

See the [Exceptions trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) and [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

What is the real path of relevant class and scores.txt

I not recomment but only one you can use full path of scores.txt file.

Comment: scores.txt is one folder upwards of the src folder (so I guess the main project folder?)

Comment: Relative paths are fine and make the program more flexible, but you do need to beware of how the program's execution location can change